# Flask-migrate doesn't update or migrate changes after environment change

Tags: flask, flask-migrate

I'm running Flask with FLask-SQLalchemy on DigitalOcean Apps. I can't get Flask-Migrate to work properly on the production environment. Calling `flask db migrate` on my production app does nothing. No changes detected. Nothing. Just this below:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

As such I tried [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-add-flask-migrate-to-an-existing-project) tutorial - which is basically a way of 'starting again'. I'd create the initial migration to a local empty DB, then commit that migration script to source and push it live. The changes (the initial migration) were detected just fine on an empty local DB. All that's changed is the DB is empty and I changed the DATABASE_URI env.

This means there's a migration for the 'first migration' on the production instance. As far as I'm aware, it reflects the state of the production DB.

I'd then run `flask db stamp head` on production and local. Running `flask db migrate` on production (with the change I want to migrate) nothing happens. No changes detected. `flask db upgrade` produces the same results. I checked the migrate instance on production - it has the correct db connection string. The web app works, but its not detecting or able to push through new changes?

I have data in my database I absolutely cannot drop it.

Comment: As I understand the tutorial, you do not expect any outcome of the `flask db upgrade` in the production environment after changing back the uri. Can you confirm that you did the following: 1. create an empty local db, 2. run the `init` and the `migrate` on that empty db, 3. change back the uri to the "real" db, 4. run the `flask db stamp head` command. I think a way to test if this worked is to do a new change, do the `migrate`and `upgrade` commands and see if it worked. Another source of error could be that you use different schema names on the databases (happened to me once)

Comment: Both databases are POSTGRES databases. I confirm I did 1. I did 2. I did 3. After I have done this - doing migrate and upgrade on a new change doesn't do anything. Nothing is detected.

Comment: I can confirm that after step 3, and running `flask db stamp head` I made a change to the schema (on local 'real' db) and no changes were detected.

Comment: have you tried to list the columns with \d in postgres and can confirm that you have the same output on both databases (name, schema, type, owner)?

Comment: also, what cme to my mind: in 3., do not change the URI but actually rename the databases and let the URI remain the same, such that the database you are referring to in your app always has the same name

Comment: Hey so, the local-development database has a different name to the live-production database. Do you think this is part of the issue? Also the 'fake' db I make to get the migration scripts has a different name also. I'll try you method of renaming things and see how I get on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228948/discussion-between-phil0s0pher-and-straeter).